# How to align links on top of each other inside of a box with CSS?

Tags: css, html, hover

My goal is to make a DIV that presents the latest four news links with the title and a small picture on `hover`.

The box will be small (150px height by 50px width) and will expand to about 500px. Once an article is clicked, it will bring up a box that you may exit out of. This box will put a dark layer on the rest of the content so that it is focused on by the user.

Anyways... here is my CSS I have currently.

```
#news {
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: blue;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}

#news a {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
}

#news:hover {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#news:hover a {
    display: block;
}
```

My HTML uses the `a` tag to edit the position, but **was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to go about making the boxes inside the div look neat and conform to my command?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<div id="news">
    <ul id="articles">
        <li class="article-item">
            <h2>Article 1!</h2>
            <p>Here is some text for the article.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="article-item">
            <h2>Article 2!</h2>
            <p>Here is some text for the article.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="article-item">
            <h2>Article 3!</h2>
            <p>Here is some text for the article.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then your styles would be something like this:

```
.article-item {
ADD STYLES HERE
}

.article-item h1{
ADD STYLES HERE
}

.article-item p{
ADD STYLES HERE
}
```

Etc...